# How to select based on a range?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table as follows:

[image]

I want to select the first row having the unit value greater or equal to 2000 and less than 3000. I can do it as follows:

```
select * from spot_shipment_fees where min_unit>=2000 AND max_unit<3000
```

But the problem is I have only one variable holding a single value like 2000. How can I generate this SQL in this situation?

```
i.e: $unit_value = 2000. 
select * from spot_shipment_fees where min_unit>=$unit_value AND max_unit<$unit_value
```

I know this is wrong but can't find the tricks to resolve it. Any idea?

Comment: Use the standard 'between' keyword, or wrap the select you want into procedure with parameter (overkill, I know, but maybe you need several places this type of code to be used...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select ssf.*
from spot_shipment_fees ssf
where ? between min_unit and max_unit;
```

`?` is a parameter placeholder for the value you want to pass in.

Comment: Thanks, dear. It works like a charm. SQL is an English like language. So nice.